# MySQL -- Keeping Track of User's Posts

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am working on a project where users will be able to make posts that will be stored in a MySQL database. I need an efficient way to list the posts of one specific user and a way to list the posts of all users. I thought about using one table for all posts, but I am afraid that that would be slow. I could also have a different table for the posts of each user, but I would then not be able to search for posts by all users. Would it be efficient to combine the two methods above, or is there a better way?

Comment: `I am afraid that that would be slow` ORLY?

Comment: Is a Post only created by a User ? If yes, creates 2 tables : Posts, Users. The table Post will conatins a foreign_key to the user id.

Comment: Yes, that would work if I wanted to search for all posts based on certain criteria, but if I only wanted one user's posts, would it not be faster to have a table of posts for each user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each post a user does, make note of his ID (a unique identifier) in the row, so that in the future you can select all the posts that a certain ID has done.

Example (pseudo sql structure):

```
tblPosts {
 PostID int(11), 
 AuthorID int(11), 
 PostText text
}

tblAuthros {
 AuthorID int(11),
 AuthorName text
}
```

This is very efficient and fast

Comment: Would that still be efficient for millions of posts? It is theoretically possible that there will be more than a million posts.

Comment: Yes it will be still effective, you need to weight in what you will have more, users, or posts, if posts, have them have a userid, if users, have them have what posts they posted. I cannot see how you would have more users than posts :]

Answer (score 0):

Create a table like so:

```
--posts--
id
post_body
user_id
date_posted
```

Where `user_id` is the unique ID of the user that created the post. Then select said posts like so:

```
SELECT id, post_body, user_id, date_posted FROM posts WHERE user_id = 8723
```